# trying to find a word that rhymes with "elk"

Tags: single-word-requests

I compose limericks and I am looking for a word that rhymes with "elk".

Comment: Have you consulted a rhyming dictionary?

Comment: Near rhymes include *milk*, *bilk*, and *ilk*.  But I agree with @choster - try a rhyming dictionary.

Comment: Lawrence Welk, obviously.

Comment: Clearly, *milk* ([Midwestern](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=melk) [dialect](http://www.city-data.com/forum/general-u-s/470065-how-do-you-pronounce-milk-4.html) pronunciation).

Answer (score 1):

Welk or whelk might be good choices.